# Is a base kitchen sink module available for install with Angular Material?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-material

[The Angular Material Stackblitz Demoes for Components come with a base module like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wehjf?file=src%2Fmaterial.module.ts).

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {CdkAccordionModule} from '@angular/cdk/accordion';
import {ClipboardModule} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {CdkListboxModule} from '@angular/cdk/listbox';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import {CdkMenuModule} from '@angular/cdk/menu';
import {DialogModule} from '@angular/cdk/dialog';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkAccordionModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkListboxModule,
    CdkMenuModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    OverlayModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    DialogModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialExampleModule {}
```

Anyone know if Angular makes this installable via the CLI?

[I've made one in the past for install from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/material-base-module), so just wanted to check before I upgrade it.

Comment: That's a bad practice, just don't do that.

Comment: I agree for production it may not be the most "Light Weight" solution ... But for prototyping its quite handy.